# How can I do a popover view with a button and then show a tableView (in popover format)?

Tags: swift, swift3, tableview, ios10, popover

I want to create a button on a UIViewController and when pressed to show a UITableView in popover format. When I try, I've got to see the tableview in popover format but I can present my content on it. Anybody knows how to correctly do a popover with a tableView? Or does anyone have an example of this situation? (the button isn't a UIBarButton, its a normal UIButton). I tried this:

```
import UIKit
```

class StadisticViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

```
var team: [Players] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


@IBAction func showPopoverTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! PopViewController
        controller.popTeam = self.team
        controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 65.0)

    }
}


func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide what exactly you have tried and any code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a popover from your View Controller
Add an anchor point on that popover by Dragging plus icon
[image: Popover From a UIView Controller and Button is Anchor]

```
class ViewController : UIViewController , UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


   @IBAction func showPopoverTapped(_ sender : UIButton) {
      self.performSegue("identifier" , sender : self)
    }




 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? YourViewControllerClass {
            controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 65.0)
        }


    }
}

  func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

**if you wanna do programmatically**

```
     else if senderTag == 2  {



    let sliderViewController =  storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BGPopover") as! AllDesignsViewController
   sliderViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
   sliderViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 220)

    let popoverMenuViewController = sliderViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    // You Still Need Anchor point for popover i used bar  button as popover anchor. you can use any other UI Element
    // popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = yourAnchorView
    // popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = yourAnchorView.bounds
    popoverMenuViewController?.barButtonItem = sideBarButton

    present(sliderViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: because there are several methods to do this

Comment: I can't try because xcode says that the constant "controller" requires an initializer. I don't know how to initializer a controller.. . Thanks for the help.

Comment: if let controller  this one?

Comment: yes, but i take off the if, but it doesn't works. I need another form. I have this:

Comment: remove if and if brackes